# Prevent users from deactivating network connection?

Tags: networking, pantheon

the network manager menu in the upper right corner of ElementaryOS provides a switch to deactive the network connection. In environments with network login this can cause freezing the current session.

Is there a way to remove/deactivate the switch for switching on/off the network?